# How come this code isn't working when I can't seem to find anything wrong?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Html and CSS work fine but for some reason, the JS won't work correctly. It seems to give a syntax error of uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getTotalLength' of null and it won't give me the length. I am following a tutorial from devEd. outline.style.strokedasharray is also not working. I really need a solution, thanks!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Meditation App</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <script>
 const app = () => {
const song = document.querySelector(".song");
const play = document.querySelector(".play");
const outline = document.querySelector(".moving-outline circle");
const video = document.querySelector(".vid-container video");

//Sounds
const sounds = document.querySelectorAll(".sound-picker button");
//Time Display
const timeDisplay = document.querySelector(".time-display");
//Get length of the outside
const outlineLength = outline.getTotalLength();
//Duration
let fakeDuration = 600;

outline.style.strokeDasharray = 100;

}; 
 
 
 app();
 </script>
 <style>
 *{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  
 }
 .app{
  height:100vh;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-evenly;
  align-items:center;
  
 }
 .time-select,.sound-picker,.player-container{
  height:80%;
  flex:1;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  justify-content:space-evenly;
  align-items:center;
  
 }
 .player-container{
  position:relative;
 }
 .player-container svg{
  position:absolute;
  height:50%;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
  pointer-events:none;
  
 }

 .time-display{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:10%;
  color:white;
  font-size:50px;
 }
 video{
  position:fixed;
  top:0%;
  left:0%;
  width:100%;
  z-index:-10;
  
 }
 .time-select button, 
 .sound-picker button{
  color:white;
  width:30%;
  height:10%;
  background:none;
  border:2px solid white;
  cursor:pointer;
  border-radius:5px;
  font-size:20px;
  transition:all 0.5s ease;
 }
 .time-select button:hover{
  color:black;
  background:white;
  
 }
 .sound-picker button{
  border:none;
  height:120px;
  width:120px;
  border-radius:50%;
 }
 .sound-picker button:nth-child(1){
  background:#4972a1;
  
 }
 .sound-picker button:nth-child(2){
  background:#a14f49;
 }


 


 
 </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="app">
<div class="vid-container">
 <video Loop>
 <source src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/wkdu9elom9o4r5g/rain%20%281%29.mp4?raw=1"/>
 </video>
 </div>
<div class="time-select">
<button data-time="120">2 Minutes</button>
<button data-time="300">5 Minutes</button>
<button data-time="600">10 Minutes</button>
</div>
<div class="player-container">
 <audio class="song">
  <source src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/jawlfpyyz83w2td/rain.mp3?raw=1"/>
 </audio>
 <svg class="play"
  width="90" height="90" viewBox="0 0 68 78" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M68 39L0.499996 77.9711L0.5 0.0288552L68 39Z" fill="white"/>
</svg>
 <svg class="track-outline"
 width="453" height="453" viewBox="0 0 453 453" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<circle cx="226.5" cy="226.5" r="216.5" stroke="white" stroke-width="20"/>
</svg>
<svg class="moving-outline"
width="453" height="453" viewBox="0 0 453 453" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<circle cx="226.5" cy="226.5" r="216.5" stroke="#018EBA" stroke-width="20"/>
</svg>
<h3 class="time-display">0:00</h3>
</div>
<div class="sound-picker">
<button data-sound="https://www.dropbox.com/s/jawlfpyyz83w2td/rain.mp3?raw=1" data-video="https://www.dropbox.com/s/wkdu9elom9o4r5g/rain%20%281%29.mp4?raw=1"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/8BspYTV/rain-1.png"></button>
<button data-sound="https://www.dropbox.com/s/6k9nauf2ffyvfuu/beach.mp3?raw=1"
 data-video="https://www.dropbox.com/s/tsdd86bxmax32jp/beach.mp4?raw=1"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/T0xw4k7/sun-umbrella.png"</button>


</div>





</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You JS code is being read and executed *before* your HTML document finishes parsing; so when the code tries to look for `.sound-picker button` for example; it can't find it because it hasn't rendered that yet; you should execute your Javascript code after your document is done loading

Comment: also you're missing a closing bracket on the last img  and a closing div tag.. just an addendum..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your entire `<script>` block to the bottom.

`outline` is null because when you are doing `const outline = document.querySelector(".moving-outline circle");` the DOM element with class `.moving-outline` doesn't exist yet, so outline is null, thus being unable to call a method from it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Meditation App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
        *{
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            box-sizing:border-box;

        }
        .app{
            height:100vh;
            display:flex;
            justify-content:space-evenly;
            align-items:center;

        }
        .time-select,.sound-picker,.player-container{
            height:80%;
            flex:1;
            display:flex;
            flex-direction:column;
            justify-content:space-evenly;
            align-items:center;

        }
        .player-container{
            position:relative;
        }
        .player-container svg{
            position:absolute;
            height:50%;
            top:50%;
            left:50%;
            transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
            pointer-events:none;

        }

        .time-display{
            position:absolute;
            bottom:10%;
            color:white;
            font-size:50px;
        }
        video{
            position:fixed;
            top:0%;
            left:0%;
            width:100%;
            z-index:-10;

        }
        .time-select button, 
        .sound-picker button{
            color:white;
            width:30%;
            height:10%;
            background:none;
            border:2px solid white;
            cursor:pointer;
            border-radius:5px;
            font-size:20px;
            transition:all 0.5s ease;
        }
        .time-select button:hover{
            color:black;
            background:white;

        }
        .sound-picker button{
            border:none;
            height:120px;
            width:120px;
            border-radius:50%;
        }
        .sound-picker button:nth-child(1){
            background:#4972a1;

        }
        .sound-picker button:nth-child(2){
            background:#a14f49;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="app">
        <div class="vid-container">
            <video Loop>
                <source src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/wkdu9elom9o4r5g/rain%20%281%29.mp4?raw=1"/>
            </video>
        </div>
        <div class="time-select">
            <button data-time="120">2 Minutes</button>
            <button data-time="300">5 Minutes</button>
            <button data-time="600">10 Minutes</button>
        </div>
        <div class="player-container">
            <audio class="song">
                <source src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/jawlfpyyz83w2td/rain.mp3?raw=1"/>
            </audio>
            <svg class="play"
            width="90" height="90" viewBox="0 0 68 78" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path d="M68 39L0.499996 77.9711L0.5 0.0288552L68 39Z" fill="white"/>
        </svg>
        <svg class="track-outline"
        width="453" height="453" viewBox="0 0 453 453" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <circle cx="226.5" cy="226.5" r="216.5" stroke="white" stroke-width="20"/>
    </svg>
    <svg class="moving-outline"
    width="453" height="453" viewBox="0 0 453 453" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <circle cx="226.5" cy="226.5" r="216.5" stroke="#018EBA" stroke-width="20"/>
</svg>
<h3 class="time-display">0:00</h3>
</div>
<div class="sound-picker">
    <button data-sound="https://www.dropbox.com/s/jawlfpyyz83w2td/rain.mp3?raw=1" data-video="https://www.dropbox.com/s/wkdu9elom9o4r5g/rain%20%281%29.mp4?raw=1"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/8BspYTV/rain-1.png"></button>
    <button data-sound="https://www.dropbox.com/s/6k9nauf2ffyvfuu/beach.mp3?raw=1"
    data-video="https://www.dropbox.com/s/tsdd86bxmax32jp/beach.mp4?raw=1"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/T0xw4k7/sun-umbrella.png"</button>


</div>





</body>
<script>
    const app = () => {
        const song = document.querySelector(".song");
        const play = document.querySelector(".play");
        const outline = document.querySelector(".moving-outline circle");
        const video = document.querySelector(".vid-container video");

        //Sounds
        const sounds = document.querySelectorAll(".sound-picker button");
        //Time Display
        const timeDisplay = document.querySelector(".time-display");
        //Get length of the outside
        const outlineLength = outline.getTotalLength();
        //Duration
        let fakeDuration = 600;

        outline.style.strokeDasharray = 100;
    };  
    app();
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use DOMContentLoaded event.
Somthing like this:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
//your code (your function)
});
```

But the reason has been already described above.

Answer (score 0):

you need to let the html document load first. using jQuery's $(document).ready() function is really helpful for this.

[jQuery .ready() documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_ready.asp)

Comment: Although it is helpful, it's not really necessary since you also have the `window.onload` event with vanilla JavaScript, using that also helps avoiding the additional library